# Cannot make header be indexed

Tags: eclipse, git, github, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have a C project in eclipse (TI code composer dist) and have recently started using egit to commit and push to github.

I recently accidentally right-clicked on a header file and selected ignore instead of what I had mean to select.

However the ignore icon overlay (the little grey x) did not show up on the file, but no other icon overlays did either! Its also is not listed in .gitgnore.

I cannot seem to get it added back to the git index, have tried add to index by multiple methods, un-tracking and re-tracking, removing the file from the project and re-adding it and so on with no change in the file status

When I try to commit it is not available to add or stage and does not seem to show up in any view or perspective in any way related to git/egit and it is not shown in github
The C source file that I created at the same time as this header was added without a mention as did a previous header I created.

Im quite a noob at git (and version ctrl systems) so am at a loss what might fix this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not listed in a `.gitignore` file? There can be more than one such file (at every directory level), so make sure you check everywhere.

Comment: Thought I'd checked that but there was *another* one in the project subdir *as well as* the project directory *and* the repo git directory. That worked!! Thanks ;)

Comment: Ok, posted the comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not listed in a .gitignore file? There can be more than one such file (at every directory level), so make sure you check everywhere.

In general, I recommend using the *Git Staging* view for committing and while working with the repository. There you should have seen the modified `.gitignore` listed after you executed Ignore.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged your-file
```

might help.

Comment: Installed git separately and browsed to the repo. in the git bash, ran the cmd as spec'd, returned "fatal: 'pathToFile/File.h' is outside repository... (where pathToFile/File.h is in a subdir in the repo)

Comment: OK, I'll try cover a little more. I have repo set up using egit in eclipse in users/user/git/RepoName/. inside that is a git dir and the project dir, the header is in a subdir of the project, as are most of the others. Didn't have gitsys installed till now (not overly sure if i'm using it right), just cd'd to the repo dir and ran the cmd as above. Is that any help?